# django-dynamic-formset: delete form then add form causes me problems

Tags: jquery, django, forms, django-forms

Using jQuery Formset 1.3-pre

If I use jquery-formset to delete an existing form, then on the same page add a new form and hit save, I get this error:

```
Request Method: POST
Django Version: 1.7
Exception Type: ValidationError
Exception Value: ["'' value must be an integer."]
```

the value causing the error appears to be:

```
self    django.db.models.fields.AutoField: id
```

It only happens when new forms are added to replace deleted ones in the one formset session. If I delete, save, add, save, it's fine. Only when I delete, add, save do I get this error.

I figure django uses the TOTAL-FORMS and INITIAL-FORMS variable to calculate whether it is dealing with new or pre-existing forms, but because my number of returned forms is the same as INITIAL-FORMS, even though one of the forms is a new one, it thinks all the forms are pre-existing ones and tries to validate the id. Something like that, anyway.

Is there a way to prefix a new form to tell django it's dealing with an added form so it doesn't try to validate the  id?

What am I missing?

thanks

John

PS May be relevant, may not be: my jquery.formset delete routine uses ajax to remove from the database any rows that correspond to existing forms. I never found any documentation on dynamically deleting forms, so I just figured that was what I should do.

Comment: don't use jquery-formset, it's a quite simple task, just do it manually (comments in Russian but I think it is not a problem):

https://bitbucket.org/madzohan/ato/src/49223a0d2417035a6aa98cdd7b9e7a3ea994c96b/apps/common/static/common/js/formsetAddForm.js?at=master

https://bitbucket.org/madzohan/ato/src/49223a0d2417035a6aa98cdd7b9e7a3ea994c96b/apps/common/templates/common/empty_formset_item.html?at=master

Answer (score 3):

If you have a formset with forms for existing instances and forms for blank lines, you need to remove the forms for existing instances from jquery-formset control by removing "dynamic" from the HTML  row class. Like this:

```
{% for a_form in my_formset %}
    <tr {% if not a_form.instance.pk %}class="dynamic"{% endif %}>
        {{ a_form.id }}
        <td>{{ a_form.a_field }}</td>
        <td>{{ a_form.another_field}}{{ a_form.another_field.errors }}</td>
        <td>{% if a_form.instance.pk %}{{ a_form.DELETE }}{% endif %}</td>
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Not only will this stop jquery-formset from messing with the forms for existing records, but it produce the delete checkbox that Django forms is expecting.

If you allow class=dynamic for your existing records, then jquery-formset will create a "remove" link that allow users to completely delete them form the POST data. You get the error message you are seeing because an existing record has been removed from the POST and replaced with a blank form. The error ["'' value must be an integer."] is referring to the fact that the ID of the record has gone from being an integer to an empty string.